# Doxygen's preprocessor seems to be evaluating some macros wrong, can I override it?

Tags: c, doxygen

I am using a third party library that includes a lot of macro's to enable and disable different sections of code. I am enabling some sections of code, but for some reason doxygen's preprocessor does not agree with my compiler's processor!

I set ENABLE_PREPROCESSING to NO and the documentation that I wanted to see was included. However, when I turn off preprocessing, I then lose the documentation on any of the macros in my project.

I reenabled preprocessing and tried to predefine the symbols that doxygen seemed to be confused about in the following manner:

```
NAME := 1.
```

This still didn't seem to solve my issues.

Is there a way to selectively disable the preprocessor to ignore certain sections of code where it seems to be having problems?

Comment: I don't know any way to locally disable the preprocessor alone, but you can locally disable doxygen processing by surrounding code segments with `@cond` `@endcond`. Is surrounding the difficult macros like this a possible route for you?

Comment: Yes, this would be fine - so far there is only one file that seems to be causing me grief. But, this does not seem to disable the preprocessing - only processing. I can exclude an element from being documented by putting \cond \endcond around it, but surrounding the #if <symbol> with \cond \endcond does not seem to do anything - it appears the macro is still getting evaluated by the preprocessor.

Comment: Well, I figured out what was causing doxygen's preprocessor to wig out... it was a #pragma error "some message,  but it didn't have a closing ". That error message wasn't going to get compiled anyway, so my compiler's preprocessor ignored it. But it caused doxygen to stumble, and all of the code sections following that were not included in my output.

Comment: Ah yes, been caught like that myself.  It would be useful to paste that into an 'answer' and accept it - then this question won't keep showing as 'needing an answer'.

Comment: I was still hoping someone might jump in and say "here is a way to locally shut down the preprocessor" - because that still might be useful someday to know. :) But I suppose you're right... I don't need to know that immediately. I've moved on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a #pragma error ", but it didn't have a closing quote. That error message was being ignored by my compiler's preprocessor due to some surrounding #ifs and thus "error: bla" didn't show up in my compiler's output. But it still caused doxygen to stumble and all of the code sections following that were not included in my output.